# Is it possible to pre-define a data table in Cucumber-jvm?

Tags: cucumber

I have a data table that is shared between many of my scenarios.  Is there a way to store the data table in something like a variable and pass it to each scenario?  That way I don't have to edit each one every time some value changes in it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @GregBurghardt
I don't really have anything special.  Just 2 different scenarios that use the same data table.
When Input data form
| First Name | Last Name |

But I don't want to have to retype this for each time the data in it changes.

Comment: @hello297 U could store it in a json file and access directly from the step definitions.

Comment: Alternatively you could use a helper method that will create the object (using a builder, if you like). You can call the helper method from your step definitions